# AngularJs custom sorting wont accept value returned from a function

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I'm calling an API my company uses that returns an array of objects, one of them looks like:

```
{ip = 127.0.0.1, 
connected: 2015-01-01 00:00:00, 
disconnected: 2015 01-01 01:00:00, 
traffic:90000}
```

I am able to create an anugular app that produces a table with `ng-repeat` that is sortable by `ip`, `connected`, and `disconnected`. The `traffic` var is the number of bytes transmitted during the session so I subtracted the dates to get the number of bytes transmitted per second and was able to display it on the table with the table looks like below. Clicking the headers will sort the table by that value and clicking it again will reverse it and display appropriate arrow. `results` is the response from the http post:

JS:

```
$scope.reverseOrder = function(predicate) {
    $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : true ;
    $scope.predicate = predicate;
};
    $scope.bytesPerSecond = function(startDate, endDate, traffic) {
        var from = moment(startDate);
        var to = moment(endDate);
        var seconds = to.diff(from, 'seconds');
        return traffic/seconds;
    };
```

HTML:

```
<table class="...">
        <thead>
            <th>
                <a href="" ng-click="reverseOrder('ip')">IP Address</a>
                <i ng-class="{'icon-arrow-down' : reverse && predicate==='ip', 'icon-arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate==='ip'}"></i>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a href="" ng-click="reverseOrder('connected')">Time Connected</a>
                <i ng-class="{'icon-arrow-down' : reverse && predicate==='connected', 'icon-arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate==='connected'}"></i>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a href="" ng-click="reverseOrder('disconnected')">Time Disconnected</a>
                <i ng-class="{'icon-arrow-down' : reverse && predicate==='disconnected', 'icon-arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate==='disconnected'}"></i>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a href="" ng-click="reverseOrder(bytesPerSecond)">Bytes per second</a>
                <i ng-class="{'icon-arrow-down' : reverse && predicate===bytesPerSecond, 'icon-arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate===bytesPerSecond}"></i>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="result in results | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
            <td style="text-align: left;">{{result.ip}}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{result.connected}}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{result.disconnected}}</td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">{{bytesPerSecond(result.connected,result.disconnected,result.traffic)| number:0}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The `reverseOrder` function works for the `ip` and dates but it will not work with the `bytesPerSecond` function. I read in the angular documentation that the `orderBy` directive can be used for values from functions but I'm not sure why it isn't working. It just displays and switches the arrow next to the header and doesn't sort the values at all. How can I get the table to sort by the `bytesPerSecond` function I created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is certainly a way to make it work using function to order, as a lazy programmer who doesn't want to find out how to do it, I'd calculate all bytes per second for each item and store it as an attribute.

```
angular.forEach($scope.results, function(value) {
  value.bytesPerSecond = $scope.bytesPerSecond(value.connected, value.disconnected, value.traffic);
});
```

And viola you can share code with other attributes =)

Comment: If possible I would not like to write to the original database, I'd rather keep the calculations locally.

Comment: The json used exists on client side memory only, how is it affecting database? Maybe in this case you can still calculate on the fly, but for something like keeping track of selected checkbox, it is best to keep in the object.

Comment: Oh nvm I thought it edited the database before I checked. Seems to work thanks.